# Append CSS class to element

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a model, i.e. like this:

```
[{
    "Name" : "Foo",
    "CssClass" : "class1"
},
{
    "Name" : "Bar",
    "CssClass" : "class2"
}]
```

Which is presented using the following template:

```
<li v-for="foobar in model">
    <span class="otherclass anotherclass">{{foobar.Name}}</span>
</li>
```

How could I append the `CssClass` property to the span?

I know you could do `:class="{ active: isActive }"` (as per the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)), but this uses a predefined class called `active`, whereas I want to append the class name from the model.

I tried using `<span class="otherclass anotherclass" :class="foobar.CssClass">` but that didn't add `CssClass` to `class` at all.

How could I go about making this work so that the `<span>` will effectively be rendered as `<span class="otherclass anotherclass class1">` (for the first model entry)? And how could I also use a default value in case `CssClass` is not defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can append the class like so

```
<li v-for="foobar in model">
    <span :class="foobar.CssClass" class="otherclass anotherclass">{{foobar.Name}}</span>
</li>
```

I ran into the same issue in the past. During render all three classes will combine into one `class="my_class_from_foobar otherclass anotherclass"`

Comment: I had already tried with `:class="foobar.CssClass"`, but that didn't yield any result at all. (I should probably have specified that in the question, so I'll do that after this comment)

Comment: It seems my error was not passing along the `.CssClass` from one model to another. I tried recreating it in jsfiddle but no matter what I did it always worked... which lead me to my own models. Thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an object or an array to `:class`. You can also use `class` and `:class` together and Vue will resolve both correctly without issues:

```
<li v-for="foobar in model">
    <span class="otherclass anotherclass" :class="[foobar.CssClass]">{{foobar.Name}}</span>
</li>
```

Comment: I had already tried with `:class="foobar.CssClass"`, but that didn't yield any result at all. I also tried with your bracket syntax `:class="[foobar.CssClass]"` but that didn't yield any results either

Answer (score 1):

```
<li v-for="foobar in model">
  <span :class="'otherclass anotherclass ' + foobar.CssClass">{{foobar.Name}</span>
</li>

<li v-for="foobar in model">
  <span :class="foobar.CssClass" class="otherclass anotherclass">{{foobar.Name}</span>
</li>
```

Both should work